# How can I plot multiple legends for multiple geopandas plot layers?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, geopandas

I want two show both legends for both of my plot layers but it shows only just one legend. How can I fix this?

```
import geopandas
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

coords_1 = ((0., 0.), (0., 1.), (1., 1.), (1., 0.), (0., 0.))
coords_2 = ((1., 1.), (2., 1.), (2., 2.), (1., 2.), (1., 1.))

d = {'vsu': [10, 15], 'geometry': [Polygon(coords_1), Polygon(coords_2)]}
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(d)

p = {'gk': ["a", "b"], 'geometry': [Point(0.5, 0.5), Point(1.5, 1.5)]}
gdf_2 = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(p)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

gdf.plot(column="vsu", scheme="EqualInterval", legend=True, ax=ax)
gdf_2.plot(column = "gk", ax=ax, legend=True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761806/matplotlib-2-different-legends-on-same-graph

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73248053/legend-in-geopandas-plot-for-color-as-well-as-for-markersize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first legend needs to be saved and then later added again to the plot.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

gdf.plot(column="vsu", scheme="EqualInterval", legend=True, ax=ax)
leg1 = ax.get_legend()

gdf_2.plot(column = "gk", ax=ax, legend=True)

ax.add_artist(leg1)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**